# How to create a newcommand with 2 different meanings for math mode and text mode?

Tags: math-mode, text-mode

I use the `\usepackage{newunicodechar}` to enter easily some unicode characters in math mode.

For example I used unicode curled phi ( ϕ ) to insert phi in math mode. The problem is that any Unicode word in text mode starting with this phi is changed to math mode! So my question is: How could  I use the  `ifmmoder` or other TeX commands to make a suitable defitition of  `\newunicodechar{ϕ}` that behaves diferently in each mode? (Unfortunately, I don't know TeX well ..)

```
% -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{Kerkis}

\newunicodechar{ϕ}{\varphi}


\begin{document} ϕαγητό \textlatin{means food}
$ϕ$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't have `Kerkis` package so this isn't tested but

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{Kerkis}

\newunicodechar{ϕ}{\ifmmode\varphi\else\textphi\fi}


\begin{document} ϕαγητό \textlatin{means food}
$ϕ$
\end{document}
```

I've use `\textphi` here but if your text Greek font has both phi forms
you could substitute a command that defined var phi in text mode.

Comment: Thank you David! My next problem is... which fonts have \textvar phi or something like that? Could you please give some ideas or maybe ask the Community?

Comment: @kornaros sorry I have no idea. My Greek language skills are restricted to math use. Do you have any greek text setup where both phis work? Perhaps you should ask a new question specifically on that.